# How to change the date format in Magento customer dashboard

Tags: date, magento, format, dashboard

I want to change the format of date for recent orders in customer account dashboard.

Now it is coming up in the format **mm/dd/yyyy**.

I want to change it to **dd/mm/yyyy**.

I tried modifying it by changing the options in **system->configuration->catalog->catalog->date & time custom options** and refreshed cache too it did not change. Kindly let me know how change it.

Answer (score 0):

Make below file one by one. Solve as below: 
1. app\code\local\KesharTechnosys{namespace_name}\Datefix{module_name}\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <eav>
                <rewrite>
                    <entity_attribute_backend_time_created>KesharTechnosys_Datefix_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created
                    </entity_attribute_backend_time_created>
                </rewrite>
            </eav>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

2.app\etc\modules\KesharTechnosys_Datefix.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <KesharTechnosys_Datefix>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </KesharTechnosys_Datefix>
    </modules>
</config>
```

3. app\code\local\KesharTechnosys{namespace_name}\Datefix{module_name}\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Time\Created.php

http://pastebin.com/6fPSdpDj

Check & execute. Hope this help.

Comment: if need any help, reply me.

Comment: Hi Keshar, I  want to change the date in the customer account dashboard. The date that appears in the recent orders list in the dashboard. Not the DOB date format. Can you kindly let me know how i can do that.